# Redesign xt Commerce Menu

Tags: php, html, menu, structure

I'm about to configure an xt Commerce 4 template for a friend.

It´s the shop under: [shop.lucas-recknagel.de](http://shop.lucas-recknagel.de)

My problem is that I´ve designed a site structure where the main category items are placed in a topmenu over the whole page content, and when I select such a main category that the the level2 menu items appearing in the left sidebar.

Here an example:

```html
<ul>
 <li class="level1">MAIN-ITEM1</li>
 <li class="level2">UNDER_01 MAIN ITEM1</li>
 <li class="level2">UNDER_02 MAIN ITEM1</li>
 <li class="level2">UNDER_03 MAIN ITEM1</li>
 <li class="level1">MAIN-ITEM2</li>
 <li class="level1">MAIN-ITEM3</li>
 <li class="level1">MAIN-ITEM4</li>
</ul>
```

So items with class level1 has to be in the top menu and level2, level3 ... has to be in the side menu.

I'm familiar with PHP, HTML, and CSS but I can't find the PHP or HTML object where the menu structure is generated.

I've already searched these files:

```
WEBSERVER/templates/mytemplate/xtCore/box_categories.html
WEBSERVER/xtCore/boxes/categories.php  
WEBSERVER/xtCore/pages/categories.php  
WEBSERVER/xtFramework/classes/class.category.php
```

But nowhere can I find the structure which is generating the menu.

First I thought box_categories.html create the structure but even when I delete these file and clean all webserver caches the menu is still working. I tried also to use an if statement to filter the output of the menu depth but menu working as usual.

So I think it is created in another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried it, but I think that xt:commerce falls back to the default template if the file box_categories.html is not found. But box_categories.html is the file that create the structure.